# Solicitud de instalación para dompdf / dompdf v0.8.2 -> satisfiable por dompdf / dompdf [v0.8.2]. - dompdf / dompdf v0.8.2 requiere ext-gd * ->

Tags: laravel

estoy teniendo el siguiente error después de clonar mi proyecto para reconstruirlo  con `composer install` y me sale el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy trabajando con laravel-valet al instalar laravel no tengo problema, y al ejecutar `composer` todo anda bien por favor alguna ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que no esté habilitado para php-cli, puede habilitar de esta manera

```
sudo phpenmod gd
```

ACTUALIZAR

Supongo que estás usando el paquete ppa: ondrej php (7.1), que te confunde con el paquete ubuntu 14.04 php predeterminado (7.7.1).

Para instalar la biblioteca php 7.1 gd desde ppa: ondrej, debe usar:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-gd
```

espero que te ayude a solucionar el problema que tienes.

[fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39384644/extension-gd-is-missing-from-your-system-laravel-composer-update)